# How to configure federated query from Google BigQuery to Google AlloyDB?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-alloydb

I am trying to configure a connection between Google BigQuery to Google AlloyDB (I want to query AlloyDB from Bigquery).
Trying to follow these instructions: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries with no much success... (seems as AlloyDB is not considered as cloud sql)

1. Can AlloyDB be queried via BigQuery federated queries?
2. What should I do to configure it?

Comment: You are correct in that AlloyDB is considered a different product from Cloud SQL.  Based on the documentation, federated queries are not yet supported for AlloyDB.  With that being say the next best would be some kind of CDC replication into BQ.

Comment: @DanielZagales apparently we use some data types (enum) that are unsupported by bigquery. So CDC using google-datastream does not work..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Daniel's comment says, AlloyDB is not the same product as Cloud SQL and federated queries are not currently implemented from BigQuery to AlloyDB.

Comment: Do you know if we can expect such feature in the near future? we seriously consider reverting from AlloyDB to CloudSQL to be able to query it from BQ. Thanks anyway

Comment: @N.N. absolutely. It's on the roadmap, but is for sure a post-GA feature being prioritized with others. I don't have a firm timeline, but I wouldn't expect it imminently. If federation is something you need now now, I'd start with Cloud SQL as the move from Cloud SQL -> AlloyDB is easy and we'll be making it easier soon (tm).

Answer (score 0):

A different method instead of doing federated queries could be to stream the data from AlloyDB to BigQuery example using [Datastream](https://cloud.google.com/datastream-for-bigquery). If using Postgres, you might also use [Artie](https://www.artie.so/)